How to redirect from _ to - in post title far all posts
After a migration of thousands of post from an instance of WPs to another i observed that the old platform replace post titles spaces with underscore _, the new one with hyphen -.
Is there any why to auto redirect every post with _ to the same url with a replace of _ with -?
I.e. if someone go to {url}/some_title I want to redirect to {url}/some-title

You can refer to this link, it might helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25434178/use-regex-to-replace-underscore-with-dash-in-urls-of-wordpress-blog
